# javax.el.MethodNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jee

Boa tarde galera, gostaria da ajuda de vocês para um erro que ainda não entendo porque ocorre.

A situação é: Tenho um método no meu managedBean listarTurmas que carrega uma lista para que posteriormente eu possa usar, já testei este método em um teste no console e funcionou perfeitamente, porém ao chamar este método via JSF é retornado o seguinte erro:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /paginaListagem.xhtml @13,90 action="#{controllerTurma.listarTurmas}": Method not found: Controller.ControllerTurma@2508befb.listarTurmas()
```

chamada JSF:

```
<h:form><h:commandButton value="Consultar" action="#{controllerTurma.listarTurmas}" /></h:form>
```

Método Listar DAO:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<T> consultarTodos(Class<T> classe){
    EntityManager em = getEM();
    List<T> objetosBuscados = null;             
    try {           
        objetosBuscados = em.createQuery("FROM "+classe.getName()).getResultList();         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return objetosBuscados;
}
```

Chamada do método no Controller:

```
public void listarTurmas(){
TurmaNegocio tn = new TurmaNegocio();
this.turmas = tn.consultarTodos();  

for (Turma turma : turmas) {
    System.out.println(turma.getDescricao());
}}
```

Comment: Como o seu MBean  controllerTurma está anotado? Qual versão do JSF você está usando? Tá usando CDI?

Comment: Então Giuliana, Uso o JSF 2.2, sobre CDI desculpe mas ainda nem sei o que é rsrs e o MBean está com as seguintes annotation: @.RequestScoped
@.ManagedBean

Comment: @user54273 Como está sua importação do `ManagedBean` ?

Comment: Já aconteceu isso comigo uma vez, experimenta colocar () ao final da chamada ao método, deixando assim: action="#{controllerTurma.listarTurmas()}", O JSF entende que listarTurmas é uma propriedade e não um método sem ().

Comment: Entao @Geferson já tentei essa opção também e não mudou em nada, andei procurando e disseram para colocar a chamada no actionListner e então o erro mudou de "javax.el.MethodNotFoundException" para "Method not found"

Comment: @DiegoAugusto, como assim importação?

Comment: @user54273 import .....ManagedBean

Comment: No seu caso o correto é utilizar o "action" e não "actionListener". mesmo assim acontece o erro?

Comment: Poste a classe do bean controllerTurma por completo, para analisarmos.

Comment: Ah, acho que sei oq é! Muda teu método listarTurmas pra retornar uma String. No fim você dá um return null mesmo, só pra testar.

Comment: Galera, consegui resolver o maldito erro, eu tinha uma biblioteca duplicada no meu build path, após remover ela misteriosamente o método funcionou, bom, não sei se isso tem realmente alguma coisa a ver com o meu erro, mas, foi a solução! obrigadoa a todos vocês de coração <3!

Comment: @user54273 que bom que conseguiu resolver o problema, você mesmo pode responder sua pergunta e marca-la como correta. Dessa forma você ajudará outras pessoas que enfrentem problemas semelhantes ao teu.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque o AP disse que o problema está resolvido, porém não postou uma resposta.